# For loop within a JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a bunch of tabs using JQuery within a JSP file. The for loop does not seem to execute more than once. I am expecting to see the two tabs + 5 tabs created. I only see the "Login", "Register" and "New Tab 0" tabs. What am I doing wrong? I am a completely new to this.  Thanks in advance for your help

Below is the entire index.jsp file and the for loop is within the script tags towards the bottom of the file

```js
$((function() {
  var tabs = $("#container").tabs();
  var maxVal = 5;
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var ul = tabs.find("ul");
    $("<li><a href='#newtab'>New Tab " + i + " </a></li>").appendTo(ul);
    $("<div id='newtab'>Name :<input type='text'></input></div>").appendTo(tabs);
    tabs.tabs("refresh");
    tabs.tabs('select', 1);
  };
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="login">
      <label for="email">Email:</label> <br /> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> <br /> <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <br /> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /> <br />
      <br /> <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
    <div id="register">
      <label for="name">Name:</label><br /> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> <br /> <label for="email">Email:</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> <br /> <label for="password">Password:</label><br /> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /> <br /> <label for="address">Address:</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="address" id="address" /> <br /> <br /> <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't you have any errors in js console?

Comment: To start debugging, I'd comment out the two calls to "tabs.tabs". I'd also remove the extra semicolon after the for loop end-brace. And I'd move the "var ul" assignment to before the loop rather than in the loop. Once you remove "tabs.tabs", do you get any farther?

Comment: probably not the cause of your problem, but id's need to be unique.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, Robert, Mark, - the confusing thing for me was that the eclipse console did not show any errors. There are also other errors pointed out by Robert, Mark and Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this specific problem by changing your line:

```
 tabs.tabs('select', 1);
```

to be

```
tabs.tabs("option", "selected", 1);
```

However, there are a few other problems here that you may want to consider. You're performing more work in your loop than necessary, and it's not clear to me where you intended each tab to be added and if you're actually adding them where you need.

Finally, do look into how to use the javascript console in whatever browser you're using.  Running your code produces an error: `Uncaught Error: no such method 'select' for tabs widget instance` which would have definitely helped you in tracking down the problem.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I did not realize that there were errors in the code as eclipse console did not show any errors

Comment: Not a problem!  In Chrome or Firefox, you can use right click + Inspect to easily bring up the developer console (or there are keyboard shortcuts listed in your view menus).  In IE/Edge I think it's F12 though I don't develop on Windows often so I'm not sure.  This is really helpful for debugging client-side errors that will never log anything back to your server.

Answer (score 0):

That's enough to illustrate the problem.
I hope jQuery is there for more than just to get the $ function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
     <li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
                
<script>
(function() {
            for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
                $( "<li><a href='#newtab"+i+"'>New Tab " + i + " </a></li>" ).appendTo("ul");
            }            
})();     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all very much! Your replies helped me debug and fix the code. Below is the code a - which is what I was expecting!

```js
    `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Empty Tabs Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
     <li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="login">
      <label for="email">Email:</label> <br /> <input type="text"
       name="email" id="email" /> <br /> <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <br /> <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /> <br />
      <br /> <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
    <div id="register">
      <label for="name">Name:</label><br /> <input type="text"
       name="name" id="name" /> <br /> <label for="email">Email:</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> <br /> <label
       for="password">Password:</label><br /> <input type="password"
       name="password" id="password" /> <br /> <label for="address">Address:</label><br />
      <input type="text" name="address" id="address" /> <br /> <br /> <input
       type="submit" value="Register">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
$((function() {
        var tabs = $("#container").tabs();
  var maxVal = 5;
   var i = 0
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var ul = tabs.find("ul");
            $( "<li><a href=#newtab_" + i + ">New Tab " + i + " </a></li>" ).appendTo(ul);
            $( "<div id=newtab_" + i + ">Name :<input type='text'></input></div>" ).appendTo(tabs);
            tabs.tabs("refresh");
            tabs.tabs("option", "active", 0);
   }
    }));
</script>

</html>`
```